# Extract terms containing symbols

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-manipulation, algorithm

I would like to be able to extract terms that contain  a symbol expression and leave the special function alone.

I have a list:

```
lista={Inactive[FoxH][{{}, {5}}, {{{b, 1/2}}, {}}, s], 
Sqrt[Pi]*Inactive[FoxH][{{}, {5}}, {{{b, 1/2}}, {}}, s], 
a*Inactive[FoxH][{{}, {5}}, {{{b, 1/2}}, {}}, s], 
(w*Inactive[FoxH][{{}, {5}}, {{{b, 1/2}}, {}}, s])/s^2, 
((1 + c)*Sqrt[Pi]*w*Inactive[FoxH][{{}, {5}}, {{{b, 1/2}}, {}}, 
s])/s^2};
```

then I need to extract from `lista` to get:

```
{{1, Sqrt[\[Pi]], a, w/s^2, Sqrt[Pi]*(1 + c)*w/s^2}}
```

I tried with:

```
 Cases[#, x_. y_ :> x, {1}] & /@ {lista}
 (*{{1, Sqrt[\[Pi]], a, 1/s^2, 1 + c}}*)
```

Looks dosen't works correctly.

**How to get correct result ?** **Thanks.**

Comment: `lista /. Inactive[_][__] :> 1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
lista /. _FoxH -> 1
```

[image]

```
lista /. x_. _FoxH :> x
```

> same result

***Update:***

For the updated version of `lista`, use

```
lista /. Inactive[__][__] -> 1
```

or

```
lista /. x_. Inactive[__][__] :> x
```

Comment: (+1).I spent a few hours on solving this problem, and here came the solution after 2 minutes.  Impressive.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk:  Get used to it.  This extraordinary (and anonymous) *kglr* solves problems like nobody else on this site.  (Perhaps he or she works for WRI... just a guess...)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use Cases, why not

```
Cases[lista,any_. *FoxH[_,_,_] :> any]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I update my question. I have  `Inactive[FoxH]`  and dosen't work ?

Comment: Mariusz, try with `Cases[lista, any_.*Inactive[__][__] :> any]`

Comment: Nasser, also: `Cases[lista, any_.*Inactive[FoxH][_, _, _] :> any]`

Comment: @E.Chan-López .Thank you.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk You're welcome, it's a pleasure to help!